# XSL for-each combine different operators

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, operators

I have this XML-file, which I need to filter in three ways:

1) Colour shold be RED or GREEN, all other colours should be filtered away

2) Category could be any category, except catB

3) Status could be any status, except MISSING or DAMAGED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="items.xsl"?>
<list>
<item>
<description>Green catA Damaged</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>GREEN</colour>
<category>catA</category>
<status>DAMAGED</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Red catA OK</description>
<include>Y</include>
<colour>RED</colour>
<category>catA</category>
<status>OK</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Green catB OK</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>GREEN</colour>
<category>catB</category>
<status>OK</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Red catB OK</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>RED</colour>
<category>catB</category>
<status>OK</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Blue catB OK</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>BLUE</colour>
<category>catC</category>
<status>OK</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Yellow catC OK</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>YELLOW</colour>
<category>catC</category>
<status>OK</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Green catA OK</description>
<include>Y</include>
<colour>GREEN</colour>
<category>catA</category>
<status>OK</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Green catB Missing</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>GREEN</colour>
<category>catB</category>
<status>MISSING</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Red catB Missing</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>RED</colour>
<category>catA</category>
<status>MISSING</status>
</item>
<item>
<description>Red catC Damaged</description>
<include>N</include>
<colour>RED</colour>
<category>catC</category>
<status>DAMAGED</status>
</item>
</list>
```

I tried one for-each for the first (positive) condition, and another for-each for the other two (negative) conditions - but how on earth should I combine them into one? Or, is there another better alternative to use instead of for-each.
Googling and checking three books haven't given me the answer, so I have a strange feeling I'm totally wrong.....

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>

            <!-- "positive" statement
        <xsl:for-each select="list/item[colour='GREEN' or colour='RED']">

            "negative" statement
        <xsl:for-each select="list/item[status!='MISSING'][status!='DAMAGED'][category!='catB']">
            -->


            <xsl:sort select="description"/>

                <itemline>
                    <description><xsl:value-of select="description"/></description>
                    <include><xsl:value-of select="include"/></include>
                    <colour><xsl:value-of select="colour"/></colour>
                    <category><xsl:value-of select="category"/></category>
                    <status><xsl:value-of select="status"/></status>
                </itemline>


        </xsl:for-each>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this XML-file, which I need to filter in three ways:
>
> 1) Colour shold be RED or GREEN, all other colours should be filtered
>   away
>
> 2) Category could be any category, except catB
>
> 3) Status could be any status, except MISSING or DAMAGED

**I would write it this way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "item[colour[. = 'RED' or . = 'GREEN'] 
          and not(category='catB' or status[. = 'MISSING' or . = 'DAMAGED'])]">
      <xsl:sort select="description"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <itemline><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></itemline>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**In case it is important to use `<xsl:for-each>`** (which is generally not the best XSLT practice), the above is equivalent to this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select=
     "item[colour[. = 'RED' or . = 'GREEN'] 
          and not(category='catB' or status[. = 'MISSING' or . = 'DAMAGED'])]">
      <xsl:sort select="description"/>
      <itemline><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></itemline>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both transformations, when applied on the provided XML document, produce the wanted, correct result**:

```
<itemline>
   <description>Green catA OK</description>
   <include>Y</include>
   <colour>GREEN</colour>
   <category>catA</category>
   <status>OK</status>
</itemline>
<itemline>
   <description>Red catA OK</description>
   <include>Y</include>
   <colour>RED</colour>
   <category>catA</category>
   <status>OK</status>
</itemline>
```

**A useful short-cut expression**:

Instead of:

```
myElem = value1 or myElem = value2 or myElem = value3 or myElem = value4 or myElem = value5
```

one can write this:

```
contains('|value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|', concat('|',myElem, '|'))
```

or, if the first argument string is the value of a variable `$myValues` :

```
contains($myValues, concat('|',myElem, '|'))
```

**Similarly, the shortcut for the value of `myElem` not one of the many values**:

```
not(contains($myValues, concat('|',myElem, '|')))
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Colour shold be RED or GREEN, all other colours should be filtered
>   away
>
> 2) Category could be any category, except catB
>
> 3) Status could be any status, except MISSING or DAMAGED

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/list">
    <list>
        <xsl:for-each select="item
                              [colour='RED' or colour='GREEN']
                              [not(category='catB')]
                              [not(status='MISSING' or status='DAMAGED')]">
            <xsl:sort select="description"/>
            <itemline>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </itemline>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```